# Estimation nonlinear panel model

Tags: panel-data, nonlinear-regression

Consider the following model on panel data:

$$Y_{it}=\alpha+\frac{\beta_i}{\beta_i+\gamma} X_{1,it} + \frac{\gamma}{\beta_i+\gamma} X_{2,it},$$

where $i$ is a cross-sectional unit index and $t$ is time. Further, $Y_{it}>0$. What would be the best way to estimate the parameters of this model?

Comment: How many time points?

Comment: Around 1000 time points, 100 cross-sectional units.

Comment: Where is the error term? To discuss estimation methods we need a full model specification, with distributions, or at least an error specification.